# Mongoose does not establish the connection with the database on Namecheap shared hosting node js application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, cpanel, shared-hosting

The flowing code successfully connects mongoose with the mlab database on localhost and Heroku. But it's not working on Namecheap node js Server.

```
 const express = require("express");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;

const server = express();

mongoose.connect("mongodb://@ds213645.mlab.com:13645/techblog", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  auth: {
    user: "user",
    password: "pass"
  }
});

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    email: String
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

server.get("/test", async (req, res) => {
  const user = new User({ name: "SomeName", email: "your@email.com" });

  const userData = await user.save();

  res.send(userData);
});

server.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.send("working");
});

server.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(`> Ready on ${port}`);
});
```

When I hit the root('/') route it works perfectly on Namecheap server but when I hit test('test') route it response 'Incomplete response received from application' after a long time. So what is the way to connect mongoose with the database on Namecheap shared hosting?

Comment: Never share your passwords

Comment: are you able to print userData

Comment: @mehta-rohan yeah it is possible in the localhost

Comment: there must be some outbound request configs in Namecheap you need to check.

Answer (score 2):

Issue solved.
The problem was Namecheap. Namecheap blocked outgoing request on port 13645. After contacting them they opened outgoing request on port 13645

Comment: Thank you, I had the similiar issue for MongoDB Atlas.

Answer (score 1):

Contact namecheap support and ask them to open the ports below

ports:
27017
3000
443 and
80

Answer (score -1):

at the first is used in local or MLAB if is MLAB try the same
mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI);
mongoose.connection

if  used the MongoDB in local try to run the mongo server from go to the location 
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin and run mongo then run Mongod after then try to run the project [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rThIA.png)
"//"name user and password
: MustName_user:password //@ds213645.mlab.com:13645/techblog", {